# Angularjs or jQuery Mobile for Hybrid apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, mobile

Okay, I've been searching to find out which one is the best between `Angularjs` and `jQuery mobile` for creating hybrid apps. specifically, an eCommerce type of app. so there won't be much animation as such apart from page transitions etc which i think both Angularjs and jQuery mobile are capable of page transitions mobile style.

I know this question has been asked before but there has been many changes to both Angularjs and jquery mobile since the last questions so I was wondering what the pros and cons are for noth.

I'm more inclined towards jquery mobile as it seems to be easier to use and also because I have never used angularjs before... but i'm willing to go towards angularjs if my app would benefit from it and if not then I can carry on with jquery mobile?

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Well from my experience, jQuery mobile does have a very nice UI for the mobile world. But I don't see why you couldn't use both, Angular for the data binding and jQuery mobile for your graphics and page transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the time constraint of the project. If you have enough time to learn AngularJS then you can do have AngularJS. 
Both of the framework are good, but as a co-developer I would follow the best practices in development which is MVC framework which is AngularJS offered.